# The correct way to obtain a ViewModel instance outside of an Activity or a Fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm building a location app where I display background locations from a Room database in my MainActivity. I can get a ViewModel by calling

```
locationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LocationViewModel.class);
locationViewModel.getLocations().observe(this, this);
```

Periodic background locations should be saved to the Room database when I receive location updates via a BroadCastReceiver. They should be saved by calling `locationViewModel.getLocations().setValue()`

```
public class LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static final String ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES =
            "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.backgroundlocationupdates.action" +
                    ".PROCESS_UPDATES";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES.equals(action)) {
                LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
                if (result != null) {
                    List<Location> locations = result.getLocations();
                    List<SavedLocation> locationsToSave = covertToSavedLocations(locations)
                    //Need an instance of LocationViewModel to call locationViewModel.getLocations().setValue(locationsToSave)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question is how should I get the LocationViewModel instance in a non-activity class like this BroadcastReceiver? Is it correct to call `locationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(context).get(LocationViewModel.class)` where context is the context that I receive from `onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)` of the BroadcastReceiver?

After getting the ViewModel, do I need to use [LiveData.observeForever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#observeforever) and [LiveData.removeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#removeObserver(android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E)) since the BroadcastReceiver is not a LifecycleOwner?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Question is how should I get the LocationViewModel instance in a
>   non-activity class like this BroadcastReceiver?

You shouldn't do that. Its bad design practice.

> Is it correct to call locationViewModel =
>   ViewModelProviders.of(context).get(LocationViewModel.class) where
>   context is the context that I receive from onReceive (Context context,
>   Intent intent) of the BroadcastReceiver?

No. It won't help

**You can achieve your desired outcome as follows:**

Separate your Room DB operation from `ViewModel` in a separate singleton class. Use it in `ViewModel` and any other place required. When Broadcast is received, write data to DB through this singleton class rather than `ViewModel`.

If you are observing for the `LiveData` in your Fragment, then it will update your views too.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought. Already got the DB singleton. `AppDatabase.savedLocationDao().saveLocations`. But it would've been more beautiful if I could just use the `locationViewModel.getLocations()` of type `MutableLiveData<List<SavedLocations>>` to update the locations.

Comment: @PrashanD Based on the documentaiton A ViewModel is always created in association with a scope (an fragment or an activity) and will be retained as long as the scope is alive. You can't achieve it with ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

It's an anti-pattern to pass the ViewModel instance around.

Ideally, the ViewModel is set up once with input stream (allowing updates like location updates thru a BroasdcastReceiver, user's actions etc.) and an output stream (for the Activity/ Fragment to observe and display to users)

Your rough dependency creation should be as follows, please us DI framework like Dagger if you can:

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedBundleState) {
    PublishSubject<List<SavedLocation>> currentLocationSubject = new PublishSubject();// here I'm using RxJava but you can use alternatives
    MyBroastcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(currentLocationSubject);
    locationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LocationViewModel.class);
    locationViewModel.setLocationInputStream(currentLocationSubject);
    locationViewModel.init();
}
```

MutableLiveData is quite similar to RxJava's Subject which is perfect for the input stream here.

**MyBroastcastReceiver**

```
static final String ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES =
            "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.backgroundlocationupdates.action" +
                    ".PROCESS_UPDATES";

    private PublishSubject<List<SavedLocation>> currentLocationSubject = new PublishSubject();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES.equals(action)) {
                LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
                if (result != null) {
                    List<Location> locations = result.getLocations();
                    List<SavedLocation> locationsToSave = covertToSavedLocations(locations)
                    currentLocationSubject.onNext(locationsToSave);// add input to the input stream
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**LocationViewModel**

```
Observable<List<SavedLocation>> inputLocationStream;
PublishSubject<List<SavedLocation>> outputLocationStream = new PublishSubject();

void setLocationInputStream(Observable<List<SavedLocation>> inputLocationStream) {
    this.inputLocationStream = inputLocationStream;
}

void init() {
    inputLocationStream.subscribe {
        saveLocationList -> {
            outputLocationStream.onNext(saveLocationList);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just observe the output stream which can be a LiveData stream instead of RxJava's Observable.

This way data really flows 1 way, compliant with MVVM architecture

Comment: I'm not trying to pass the ViewModel around.  `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ABC.class);` is the documented way of obtaining a ViewModel for the scope of ABC.class, where ABC is an Activity or a Fragment. Passing `locationViewModel.getLocations()` to a BroadCastReceiver would be an even bigger anti-pattern.

Comment: @ericn means Do I need two object, one is rxjava publishsubject and livedata for change in activity?