# Instantiating a ViewModel from a Class

Tags: java, android, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

The situation:
Upon receiving an SMS, the `MyReceiver` class extracts the SMS and should then use a `ViewModel` object to insert data into a database.
The documentation focuses on instantiation from a class extending `AppCompatActivity`, but is it necessary to pass an existing activity's ownership to the `ViewModelProvider` constructor?

The problem:
Getting access to a ViewModel Object from a public class (not an activity).

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
      mMyViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(??).get(MyViewModel.class);
   }
}
```

Attempted solutions:
In order to pass `this` to the `ViewModelProvider` constructor I tried to make `MyReceiver` implement `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner`. This requires overriding the method `getViewModelStore`. But I do not understand what a ViewModelStore is or how to create it to return a ViewModel.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewModelStore getViewModelStore(){
   return ??; 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The correct way to obtain a ViewModel instance outside of an Activity or a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007271/the-correct-way-to-obtain-a-viewmodel-instance-outside-of-an-activity-or-a-fragm)

Comment: it absolutely does, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem similiar to this question [The correct way to obtain a ViewModel instance outside of an Activity or a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007271/the-correct-way-to-obtain-a-viewmodel-instance-outside-of-an-activity-or-a-fragm)

You shouldn't instantiate the viewmodel in non activity/fragment class. In your case, when onReceive triggered you should "inform" the activity/fragment then do your action on that activity/fragment. so the instantiation of viewmodel should be done on your activity/fragment.