# How to get Data out of a Room-Database in a non-Activity. (in a JobIntentService for a notification)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-room, android-viewmodel

I want to get a List from my Room-Database for a notification, where I use a BroadcastReceiver and a JobIntentService.

Because I don't have a context I can't obtain the ViewModel.
So I need another way to get the data.

In [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51007271/11322034) I read something about a Singleton.
But I don't know how to get the data now from the database with the Singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue like this:
I saved the important data I need for the notification in Shared Preferences.
In the BroadcastReceiver I can retrieve the data from the Shared Preferences and use it in the notification.