# Cannot inject viewmodel inside Broadcast Receiver class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have an application where i want to trigger a notification , notification data comes from an api request , i'm using mvvm pattern with which i'm injecting the viewmodel using dagger-hilt , it works well in my activities and fragments but when i tried to inject it into my broadcast receiver , it is not working and i don't know what is actually wrong with the code , any help is appreciated guys , thank you .

- This is the code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AlarmReceiver  :  BroadcastReceiver () {
   @Inject lateinit var leagueViewModel : LeagueViewModel
   override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
       AlarmHelper.setAlarm(context!!)
       if(Constants.checkConnectivity(context)){
           if(intent?.action == "intent.action.android.games"){
               //Using the viewmodel insid this function to get data from api
               fireGameNotification(context,leagueViewModel)              
           }
       }
   }
```

- This is the error occuring

```
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
```

Comment: in other classes like Activity/Fragment it's work?

Comment: It's not good idea to use Viewmodel in BroadcastReceiver https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007347/11085663

Comment: Thank you guys for answering , well yeah i was told to not use it in Broadcast receiver as it is not good practice , so i move the code to my activity , thank you

Answer (score 0):

My approach for this is:

1. When receive the broadcast, save the data into `DataStore` (replacement of `SharedPreference`) or `Room` database.
2. Observe the `DataStore` or database changes in your `ViewModel` (using `Flow` or `LiveData`).